# Next JS - Connection Closed Error Resulting In Blank Page (Hosted on Vercel)

Tags: next.js, vercel, next.js13, app-router

I am running into this issue when calling `router.refresh()` on specific pages. Not sure what's causing it and this issue has persisted across Next JS versions 13-14 while using the app router. This Error is only happening in production, hosted on Vercel, I am unable to reproduce this in development or locally in production. I have attached a Highlight.io screenshot below. Has anyone encountered this at all? If so, any advice will be helpful.

[View Screenshot Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omrTH.png)

We removed loading.tsx and we believe it improved the rate at which the error occurred but it did not go away. Still happening frequently.

Comment: I am also gettng the same issue, did you find any solution mate?